# Convert Boolean true to True in a string in python using regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, dictionary

I am new to python. I have a string which looks like below

```
 """[{"key":"aadsas","doc":{"uniq_id":"false key","retail_price":799,"offer":false}},{"key":"aadsas","doc":{"uniq_id":"false key","retail_price":799,"offer":true}},{"key":false,"doc":{"uniq_id":"false key","retail_price":799,"offer":true}}
]"""
```

I need to convert it to list of dict using `ast`. But it shows `malformed string error` due to `false` in `offer` key.
I know python accepts `True` as a Boolean value and not `true`. So I am using `re` module to convert it to `False` but in the String, there are more `false` or `true` occured in it.
I need all the unique boolean value in the string to python boolean values. I don't know the `regex` format to change it. Help me with some solutions.

```
import re, ast 
a= """[{"key":"aadsas","doc":{"uniq_id":"false key","retail_price":799,"offer":false}},{"key":"aadsas","doc":{"uniq_id":"false key","retail_price":799,"offer":true}},{"key":false,"doc":{"uniq_id":"false key","retail_price":799,"offer":true}}
]"""
a = ast.literal_eval(a)
print(a)
```

Required Output:

```
[{"key":"aadsas","doc":{"uniq_id":"false key","retail_price":799,"offer":False}},{"key":"aadsas","doc":{"uniq_id":"false key","retail_price":799,"offer":True}},,{"key":False,"doc":{"uniq_id":"false key","retail_price":799,"offer":True}}
]
```

Comment: You should use `json` instead of `ast` module.

Comment: How to make it..

Comment: https://ideone.com/NjnSZN

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew , Thanks.. it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment section above, you should use [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module instead, and more specifically [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads):

```
>>> l="""[{"key":"aadsas","doc":{"uniq_id":"false key","retail_price":799,"offer":false}},{"key":"aadsas","doc":{"uniq_id":"false key","retail_price":799,"offer":true}},{"key":false,"doc":{"uniq_id":"false key","retail_price":799,"offer":true}} ]"""
>>>
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(l)
[{'key': 'aadsas', 'doc': {'uniq_id': 'false key', 'retail_price': 799, 'offer': False}}, {'key': 'aadsas', 'doc': {'uniq_id': 'false key', 'retail_price': 799, 'offer': True}}, {'key': False, 'doc': {'uniq_id': 'false key', 'retail_price': 799, 'offer': True}}]
```